# Android new Activity Extending ActionBar class instead of Activity class

Tags: android

I have eclipse(Kepler) and latest sdk installed. Whenever i create a new activity inside android project, activity is extending `ActionBarActivity`. But i need new activity to extend `Activity.class`. How to do this?

Comment: Just remove the `extends ActionBarActivity` and extend `Activity`. remvoe reference to AppCOmpat

Comment: I can do that. But is there any way that new activity extends Activity class automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to extend an class with Activity.Class automatically other than changing declaration of the class manually.